# Comando de voz que aciona um botão no aplicativo Android

Tags: java, android

Sou iniciante em Android e fiz uma estrutura para speech to text, gostaria de saber como acionar um botão dentro do aplicativo usando essa função.

Answer (score 0):

Ola, voce ja consegue capturar o texto certo?
caso ainda não este tutorial exemplifica tudo: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

se você implementou de forma parecida dentro do metodo onActivityResult basta comparar o retorno da voz com a acao e chamar o Runnable que foi vinculado ao botao.

EDIÇÃO

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button botaoAcao;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        botaoAcao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                acaoDoBotao().run();
            }
        });
    }

    private Runnable acaoDoBotao() {


        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //acao do botao
            }
        };
    }
```

E dentro do onActivityResult para chamar o botao basta chamar o `acaoDoBotao().run();`

Comment: Consigo capturar o texto sim e transformar em string , o que me complico é só como chamo o botão

Comment: entendi... vou editar na resposta acima um exemplo.